# How to active a tab when a pagination links is clicked in that tab?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

When user accesses "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1" he goes to a page like below that has 3 tabs, one for the user to edit his acccount, other (My Tickets) for the user to access information about his registrations in congresses and other (My Congresses) for the user to access the information of congresses created by him. The default tab when this page is acessed his the "Edit user account".

[image]

The tab1 content is for the user to edit his profile. When user click in "Update" the code goes to the UserController to update the user info.

When the user click in the tab2 (My Tickets) the content of this tab is like below. It shows the registrations in congresses of the user. Inside this tab content it appears also 2 tabs for the user to show his registrations in congresses that already finish and other tab to show his registrations in congresses that have not yet been performed.

Then there is the pagination if there are more than 5 results, when the user change to link "2" he goes to "http://proj.test/user/profile?page=2".

[image]

When the user click in the tab3 (My Congresses) the content of this tab is like below. It shows the congresses created by the user. Inside this tab content it appears also 3 tabs, one (Draft) for the user to show the congresses created by him that have the column "status" as "D", other (Published) to show the congresses created by the user that have the column "status" as "P" and other (Archived) to show the congresses created by the user that already finished.

Then there is the pagination if there are more than 5 results, when the user change to link "2" he goes to "http://proj.test/user/profile?page=2".

[image]

**Doubt:**

The issue with this context is that when a pagination link is clicked in some tab, for example if the user is in the tab "Draft" inside "My Congresses" tab, and clicks in the pagination link "2", the url changes to "http://proj.test/user/profile?page=2" but the tab that become active his the first one, the "Edit user account" tab. Then if the user clicks in "My Congresses" it appears the results of the page 2, but the user needs to manually click in the "My Congresses".

Do you know how to turn, in this case, the "My Congresses" tab active when a pagination page link is clicked in the "My Congresses" tab?

**Full code on this page to show all the tabs:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#updateUserInfo" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Edit user account</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#myCongresses" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">My Congresses</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#myTickets" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">My Tickets</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="updateUserInfo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <form method="post" action="{{route('user.updateUserInfo')}}" class="clearfix">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" value="{{$user->name}}" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" >
                </div>
               <!--other form fields-->
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn" value="Update"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="myCongresses" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active border" href="#draftCongresses" data-toggle="tab"
                       role="tab">Draft</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link border" href="#publishedCongresses" data-toggle="tab"
                       role="tab">Published</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link border" href="#archivedCongresses" data-toggle="tab"
                       role="tab">Archived</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <div class="tab-content bg-white" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active show clearfix" id="draftCongresses" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($draftCongresses as $draftCongress)
                        @if(!empty($draftCongress))
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <p>{{$draftCongress->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                                <h5>{{$draftCongress->name}}</h5>
                                <a href="{{route('congress.edit', ['id' => $draftCongress->id])}}" class="btn">Edit Congress</a>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    {{$draftCongresses->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade show clearfix" id="publishedCongresses" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($publishedCongresses as $publishedCongress)
                        @if(!empty($publishedCongress))
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <p>{{$publishedCongress->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                                <h5>{{$publishedCongress->name}}</h5>
                                <a href="{{route('congress.edit', ['id' => $publishedCongress->id])}}"
                                   class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit Congress</a>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    {{$publishedCongresses->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade show clearfix" id="archivedCongresses" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($archivedCongresses as $archivedCongress)
                        @if(!empty($archivedCongress))
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <p> {{$archivedCongress->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                                <h5>{{$archivedCongress->name}}</h5>
                                <a href="{{route('congress.edit', ['id' => $archivedCongress->id])}}"
                                   class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit Congress</a>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>

                <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    {{$archivedCongresses->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="myTickets" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">

        <div class="d-flex mb-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active border" id="nextCongresses" href="#nextCongresses" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Next Congresses</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link border" id="pastCongresses" href="#pastCongresses" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Past Congresses</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nextCongresses" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                <ul class="list-group" id="nextCongressesContainer">
                    @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
                        @if(!empty($nextRegistration->congress || !empty($nextRegistration->congress->start_date)))
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <p>{{optional($nextRegistration->congress)->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                                <h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->congress)->name}}</h5>
                                <p> Registration in {{optional($nextRegistration->congress)->created_at }}</p>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>

                <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    {{$nextRegistrations->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="pastCongresses" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                <ul class="list-group" id="pastCongressesContainer">
                    @foreach($pastRegistrations as $pastRegistration)
                        @if(!empty($pastRegistration->congress || !empty($pastRegistration->congress->start_date)))
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <p>{{optional($pastRegistration->congress)->start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                                <h5>{{optional($pastRegistration->congress)->name}}</h5>
                                <p> Registration in   {{$pastRegistration->created_at}}</p>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>

                <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    {{$pastRegistrations->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UserController:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){

        $pageLimit = 5;

        $user = $request->user();

        $pastRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['congress' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '<', now());
        }])->paginate($pageLimit);

        $nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['congress' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
        }])->paginate($pageLimit);

        $draftCongresses = $user->congresses()->where('status','D')->paginate($pageLimit);
        $pastCongresses = $user->congresses()->where('end_date','<', now())->paginate($pageLimit);
        $publishedCongresses = $user->congresses()->where('status','P')->paginate($pageLimit);

        return view('users.index',
            compact('user', 'pastRegistrations','nextRegistrations', 'draftCongresses', 'pastCongresses', 'publishedCongresses'));
    }
}
```

**Example of the issue**

If pagination link "2" is clicked here:

[image]

Instead of appear the page with the "My Congresses" tab active like the image above but with the pagination link "2" active instead of the pagination link "1" active, it appaers the page with the default active tab "Edit user account":

[image]

Comment: Can you show the JS that handles the `.active` class on the tabs?

Comment: Im using bootstrap 4 default js. Without this "<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
" the tabs dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these:

```
{{$draftCongresses->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
{{$publishedCongresses->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
{{$archivedCongresses->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
{{$nextRegistrations->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
{{$pastRegistrations->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
```

..to these: (i.e. add the corresponding link fragment)

```
{{$draftCongresses->fragment('draftCongresses')->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
{{$publishedCongresses->fragment('publishedCongresses')->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
{{$archivedCongresses->fragment('archivedCongresses')->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
{{$nextRegistrations->fragment('nextCongresses')->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
{{$pastRegistrations->fragment('pastCongresses')->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}
```

Then add this JavaScript/jQuery script to the page:

```
<script>
jQuery( function( $ ){
    // List of tab IDs.
    var tabs = {
    // PARENT_TAB_ID: [ 'ID_OF_DIRECT_CHILD_TAB', 'ID_OF_DIRECT_CHILD_TAB', ... ]
        updateUserInfo: [],
        myCongresses: [ 'draftCongresses', 'publishedCongresses', 'archivedCongresses' ],
        myTickets: [ 'nextCongresses', 'pastCongresses' ]
    };

    // Default tab's ID.
    var default_tab = 'updateUserInfo';

    function showTab( parent_id, child_id ) {
        $( 'a[data-toggle="tab"][href="#' + parent_id + '"]' ).first().click();

        if ( child_id ) {
            $( 'a[data-toggle="tab"][href="#' + child_id + '"]' ).first().click();
        }
    }

    $( window ).on( 'load hashchange', function(){
        var tab_id = location.hash || '';

        // Remove the hash (i.e. `#`)
        tab_id = tab_id.substring(1);

        if ( tab_id && tabs[ tab_id ] ) {
            showTab( tab_id );
        } else if ( tab_id ) {
            $.map( tabs, function( child_ids, parent_id ){
                if ( $.inArray( tab_id, child_ids ) > -1 ) {
                    showTab( parent_id, tab_id );
                }
            } );
        } else {
            showTab( default_tab );
        }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bootstrap tabs, you need to append the right fragment to your pagination links in order to maintain the active tab.

For exemple you can do something like this

```
{{ $draftCongresses->fragment('myCongresses')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4") }}
```

You can see the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

Comment: Thanks, now for example if the pagination link "2" is clicked the url changes to "http://proj.test/user/profile?page=2#myCongresses". But the active tab in the page is the "#updateUserInfo" tab. Do you know to change the active tab to the "#myCongresses"?

Comment: You have a `&quot;` at the end of the URL that messes it up. Try to copy and past the exact line I wrote and tell if it’s ok now

Comment: Thanks, but without ";" also the tab dont changes, the url changes to  "proj.test/user/profile?page=2#myCongresses" but the tab that stays active is "#updateUserInfo", that is the default tab.

Comment: The only difference is "{{ $draftCongresses->fragment('myCongresses')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4") }}" insetad of "                    {{$draftCongresses->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}".

Comment: Maybe is necessary some jQuery, like this "https://jsfiddle.net/mww3w64L/" is not working, the url changes to "proj.test/user/profile?page=2#myCongresses" but the tab that stays active is "#updateUserInfo", that is the default tab.

Comment: Like this also dont works "$(".page-item").click(function() {
        
            $('[href="#myCongresses"]').tab("show");
        });".

Comment: I think you need some JS, you get the hash in the URL with `window.location.hash` and on the page load, show the right tab with `$().show()`

Comment: Thanks, like this " $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target).attr("href")
            $('a[href="#'+target+'"]').addClass('active');
        });" is also not working, the target shows #myCongresses correctly but the tab dont stay active when the page link 2 is clicked.

Comment: I don’t think you need to listen for an event, just on the page load should be enough